# How to check web page for changes from terminal?

Tags: command-line, browser, headless

Is there a way to check if a web page changes using the command line? Something like this:

```
$ check-for-changes https://bbc.co.uk/web-page

https://bbc.co.uk/web-page just changed
```

Using a headless browser or some other mechanism?

Comment: This is not clear-cut. "Web page" usually means a lot of *different* files (contents, icons, images, ...). You have to have a clear idea what changes you are interested in.

Comment: I am interested in changes to the html. this is for a parcel tracking site - I'd like to see when there is any changes/progress to the delivery without loading every 5 mins.

Answer (score 3):

The site may serve pages with a LAST-MODIFIED header: do a HEAD request and extract that header.

```bsh
curl --silent --head https://glennj.github.io | grep -i '^last-modified:'
```

Not all sites  return that header though.

Comment: the site has a `Date` response header, but not last-modified. The page is dynamically generated, so the 'Date` is always the time of request. I guess I would need to know when the html changes.

Comment: Have you experimented with DopeGhoti's answer?

Answer (score 2):

First, get a fingerprint for the current state as a baseline:

```
curl --silent www.example.com | md5sum > www.example.com.md5
```

Then, you can subsequently check to see if the fingerprint changes:

```
curl --silent www.example.com | md5sum > www.example.com.md5new
if ! cmp www.example.com.md5 www.example.com.md5new > /dev/null; then
    printf "%s has changed from baseline!\n" "www.example.com"
fi
rm www.example.com.md5new
```

Comment: `! cmp -s www.example.com.md5 www.example.com.md5new` if you don't need the actual diff.